# How can you verify an incoming Twilio sms?

Tags: security, twilio

I basically am trying to allow users to post to their blog using a text message. I have a phone number stored for each user, and since twilio sends that information in the post request they hand to my page, I can do a reverse lookup to see which blog to post it to. The question now arises, how can I be sure that the user sent the text? Can't anyone just send post information with someone else's phone number?

I have a couple thoughts about this:
1. Twilio sends your account number in the post, which I suppose isnt known to malicious users.
2. I could respond with an SMS containing a randomly generated code, and have the user send that back. This would effectively triple the SMSs needes do I would prefer the first.

Is number one "safe enough"? Or should I bite the bullet and make a response system as in number two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can verify that requests are coming from Twilio. We attach an `X-Twilio-Signature` header to each request which is signed with your Auth Token (which should be known only by you). Each of the Twilio helper libraries has a function to help determine if the request was made by Twilio or not.

Please see our documentation on validating requests: http://www.twilio.com/docs/security#validating-requests

or our helper library functions for validating Twilio requests: http://readthedocs.org/docs/twilio-php/en/latest/usage/validation.html#validate-incoming-requests, for example.

Comment: Isn't the question more about verifying the user than verifying Twilio? ... UserA sends SMS to Twilio#, Twilio alerts service, service verifies UserA's identity ... The piece that needs to be verified is the first SMS.

Comment: I don't believe so. For inbound SMS, Twilio makes a HTTP request to a URL that you specify. The author was worried that anyone can 'fake' that HTTP request and post to the person's blog. This is why Twilio signs requests.

Comment: I see. I read "Can't anyone just send post information with someone else's phone number?" and thought about Caller ID spoofing as opposed to illegitimate Request URL activity.

Comment: I would think that any Twilio consumer should check the X-Twilio-Signature header for authenticity.. anyway, as James mentioned that would not protect against caller id spoofing (which is what happened in the News International hacking scandal). A more secure solution for that could be a 3 or 4 digit/character pin code embedded in the SMS.